# create single EXT4 partition?

Tags: gparted, disk-management

I am currently using ubuntu and windows 7. I don't want to use windows anymore , hence i deleted windows partition.

after deleting my windows partition it created 2 unallocated partition **(Please see the screenshot)**

**How to make Single EXT4 Partition from  these 2 Un-allocated partition**

[image]

Comment: You need to get out of  `41 GB` unallocated space from the extended partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your root filesystem is already mounted (see the lock icon and 'Mount Point' label), therefore you cannot modify this partition. As you can see in the tree structure, the first 42 GiB is located in the extended partition while the second 100 GiB is located outside the extended partition.

Follow these steps to make a single EXT4 partition:

1. Boot into a Live USB or CD to ensure that the root partition can be unmounted.
2. Enlarge the extended partition (`/dev/sda1`).
3. Enlarge the root partition (`/dev/sda5`).
4. Apply.
5. Reboot.

Comment: IIRC resizing from GParted tends to change the UUID.

Comment: @muru I have never seen the UUID because of a resize. It is also unnecessary as the UUID is just an identifier to the partition, not a fingerprint of the dimensions.

Comment: Besides, this change adds extra space to the right, not to the left. So no data needs to be moved which makes it a relatively safe operation.

Comment: I know, I have used `resize2fs` and `fdisk` to resize the partition/filesystem without changing the UUID. But GParted has changed the UUID on me on a couple of occasions.

Comment: By default, GParted operations leave the existing UUID alone.  The exceptions to this are:  (a) when creating a new file system -- not copy, and (b) when choosing the "Partition -> New UUID" menu option.  Note that many GNU/Linux distributions use the UUID to mount partitions -- see the /etc/fstab file.